# Django model: use generator to create data

Tags: django, django-models, generator

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class ab(models.Model):
   a = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
   b = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Now instead of

```
ab(a = 'a', b = 'b').b
```

I can do this

```
ab('a', 'b').b
```

And it will return me 'b' in both cases. So this gives me some hope.

I'm writing a map between two databases and I need something like this:

```
def createRecord(table, row):
    return table([x for x in row])
```

However it does not insert data in all columns, but just a list in the first column. Is it somehow possible to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: please note this question has got nothing to do with python generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
return table(*row)
```

I think a better practice is to pass keyword-args when creating a Model object.  If you already have field names in a list `fields`, you can do:

```
return table(**dict(zip(fields, row)))
```

If you don't, you can grab it using something like:

```
fields = [ f.name for f in ab._meta.fields ]
```

(You might choose to filter out the `id` field).

By the way, `table([x for x in row])` is the same as `table(row)` (except that it doesn't created a copy, but in this case it shouldn't matter).